# Generics OR decomposition? what is the right approach for react

Tags: reactjs, redux, functional-programming, react-hooks

I have an application developed in Angular with typescript which has 20+ screens with list views of different entities, such as List of Movies, List of Actors, List of theatres etc. I have created a `BaseListComponent<T extends Base>` in angular and encapsulated most of the common functions such as view, filter, delete, search, pagination etc into this `BaseListComponent`. And I am creating children of it like `MoviesListComponent extends BaseListComponent<Movies>`. This way I need to add minimum functionality into children classes which reduces scope of errors and also efforts for unit test cases.

Now I am converting this application into React with typescript. I was studying about react hooks and learnt that many developers are preferring function based approach over classes based components. How can I create above structure with functions. As per my understanding there is no inheritance in functions. So I am doubtful if Generics will be feasible with functions. If not, how can I solve this problem using react's popular approach of decomposition? 
Is there any guideline for using Generics or decomposition in react?

Comment: React prefers [Composition over Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). And advanced concepts like the container pattern and [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) handle situations where you may be used to reaching for generics for polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

To do it "react style", first you have to make a component `BaseListComponent`. Then put the functions you listed "view, filter, delete, search, pagination etc" in this one. But whenever you want some functions to behave differently for deriving classes, you put a callback in that function.

For example:

```
renderView = () => { // function of BaseListComponent
  const header = (
    <div>--I am Header--</div>
  );
  const footer = () => (
    <div>--------</div>
  );
  const letDerivedClassDecide = this.props.renderCenter();
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        {header}
        {letDerivedClassDecide}
        {footer}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This example means, you could control the basic layout as a vertical flex div, but you let the deriving class implement the `this.props.renderCenter`, so that its result can be combined with basic layout.

```
view = () => { // function of BaseListComponent
  let someResult = 100;
  someResult = this.props.view();
  return someResult;
}
```

The same idea, `this.props.view` is implemented by deriving class.

Finally in the deriving class it would be like:

```
render() { // function of DeriveComponent; can be MoviesListComponent
  return (
    <BaseListComponent
      renderCenter={this.renderCenter}
      view={this.view}
    >
  );
}
```

Note that, the deriving class is **not actually "derive" or extends** the base component, it just composite it in the `render()` function. So both `BaseListComponent` and `MoviesListComponent` extends `React.Component` (or `React.PureComponent` when considering performance issue).